# Facebook login not returning back when cancelled or no internet to app (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, authentication

I have configured just like in facebook document

The problem is i can login when there is internet , but when user cancelled or no internet its not coming back to app.

I am using a button to call fblogin

Here is my Appdelegate.swift

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
   return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }

 func application(application: UIApplication,
                     openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {

        if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
//            var options: [String: AnyObject] = [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey: sourceApplication!,
//                                                UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey: annotation]
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
      //  applicationHandleOpenURL(url)

        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url,
                                                    sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
                                                    annotation: annotation) || FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
    }


    @available(iOS 9.0, *)
    func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool {
        applicationHandleOpenURL(url)

        let sourceApplication: String? = options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] as? String
         FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: nil)


        print(FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: nil))
        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url,
                                                               sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] as? String,
                                                               annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]) || FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: nil)
```